# Passing a MailMessage object to a web service

Tags: web-services

Can anyone please tell me if it's possible to pass a
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage object to a ASP.NET Web Service? Maybe using XML
Serialization / Deserialization? I've been asked to investigate the
possibility of building a front-end web page which captures MailMessage
properties such To, From Subject, Attachments etc, builds a MailMessage
object, passes the MailMessage object to a web service, the web service then
sends the message via the Smtp.Send method.

Any assistance gratefully received. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly this can be done using web services. WCF would make this extremely simple. Just create a new WCF web service and the method would look something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool ReceiveMailMessage(MailMessage mm)
{
   //Send the MM
   return true;  
}
```